# Website unresolved via OSX Safari

Tags: safari, dns

## Issue

URL does not resolve: see 'dig test results'

[image]

- Safari 11.1.2
- System Version:  OS X 10.11.6 (15G22010)
- Kernel Version:  Darwin 15.6.0
- Boot Volume: Macintosh HD
- Boot Mode:   Normal

The website is correctly resolved with with Windows 7 via (IE and Chrome) at the house router.  IOS 12 devices also are unable to access the website via the router, but cellular access to website is working

## QUESTION

What OSX or Safari controls can be configured to resolve the website?

## dig test results from home router

```
ASUSWRT-Merlin RT-AC68U_3.0.0.4 Fri Jul 17 03:17:04 UTC 2015 NYC@ROUTER:/tmp/home/root# ping fbo.gov PING fbo.gov (35.169.96.154): 56 data bytes ^C
--- fbo.gov ping statistics --- 10 packets transmitted, 0 packets received, 100% packet loss
```

```
Users-MacBook-Air:~ user$ dig fbo.gov

; <<>> DiG 9.8.3-P1 <<>> fbo.gov ;; global options: +cmd ;; Got answer: ;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: SERVFAIL, id: 54519 ;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION: ;fbo.gov.          IN  A

;; Query time: 954 msec ;; SERVER: 8.8.8.8#53(8.8.8.8) ;; WHEN: Wed Oct  3 11:09:17 2018 ;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 25

Users-MacBook-Air:~ user$ dig google.com

; <<>> DiG 9.8.3-P1 <<>> google.com ;; global options: +cmd ;; Got answer: ;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 7203 ;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 11, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION: ;google.com.           IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION: google.com.      238 IN  A   74.125.232.174 google.com.      238 IN  A   74.125.232.168 google.com.      238 IN  A   74.125.232.160 google.com.      238 IN  A   74.125.232.161 google.com.      238 IN  A   74.125.232.166 google.com.      238 IN  A   74.125.232.162 google.com.      238 IN  A   74.125.232.164 google.com.      238 IN  A   74.125.232.163 google.com.      238 IN  A   74.125.232.167 google.com.      238 IN  A   74.125.232.165 google.com.      238 IN  A   74.125.232.169

;; Query time: 181 msec ;; SERVER: 8.8.8.8#53(8.8.8.8) ;; WHEN: Wed Oct  3 11:09:29 2018 ;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 204
```

## UPDATE:

Target website resolves at Starbucks.  Is it a combination of configuration adjustments on the router **and** the Macbook that are required to enable DNS?

## STARBUCKS DNS TEST RESULTS:

```
Users-MacBook-Air:~ user$ nslookup fbo.gov Server:      8.8.8.8 Address:    8.8.8.8#53

Non-authoritative answer: Name: fbo.gov Address: 34.236.209.128 Name:   fbo.gov Address: 35.169.96.154

Users-MacBook-Air:~ user$ dig fbo.gov

; <<>> DiG 9.8.3-P1 <<>> fbo.gov
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 49081
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 2, AUTHORITY: 5, ADDITIONAL: 7

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;fbo.gov.           IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
fbo.gov.        10509   IN  A   35.169.96.154
fbo.gov.        10509   IN  A   34.236.209.128

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
fbo.gov.        84586   IN  NS  dns5.gsa.gov.
fbo.gov.        84586   IN  NS  dns.gsa.gov.
fbo.gov.        84586   IN  NS  dns3.gsa.gov.
fbo.gov.        84586   IN  NS  dns2.gsa.gov.
fbo.gov.        84586   IN  NS  dns4.gsa.gov.

;; ADDITIONAL SECTION:
dns.gsa.gov.        12642   IN  A   159.142.136.198
dns.gsa.gov.        12642   IN  AAAA    2620:0:150:280f::5
dns2.gsa.gov.       12642   IN  A   159.142.150.68
dns3.gsa.gov.       12642   IN  A   34.195.166.35
dns4.gsa.gov.       12642   IN  A   159.142.69.84
dns4.gsa.gov.       12642   IN  AAAA    2620:0:150:4013::5
dns5.gsa.gov.       12642   IN  A   159.142.45.20

;; Query time: 304 msec
;; SERVER: 208.67.222.222#53(208.67.222.222)
;; WHEN: Wed Oct  3 14:53:18 2018
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 291
```

Comment: I can get to this site on Safari, Firefox and Google Chrome, latest versions, on macOS 10.13.6; and also on the latest versions of the same apps in my iPhone running iOS 12. I see that your using Google's DNS servers (8.8.8.8.) Have you tried other DNS servers? Also - what version of macOS and Safari are you using?

Comment: The error message from Safari doesn't mean it didn't resolve.  It means that it couldn't connect.  The question is, can you *ping* that server?  Also, if you issue the command `curl http://www.fbo.gov` you get a 301 error message redirecting you to the same URL but with an `https` protocol.

Comment: Good questions.   I have updated the OP to address configuration questions and added test results from the Starbucks Wifi connection.   I did not try other DNS servers because the Google DNS servers able to resolve the FQDN on the PC (Windows 7).

Comment: @Allan: The dig URL command did not return an IP address in the home router test, but did return a IP address at Starbucks: doesn't his confirm it is a DNS resolution issue?  I have update the post with the dig results

Comment: What do you get with a *ping*?   Also, why are you forcing the DNS server 8.8.8.8.  And given that it seems manually set somewhere (rather than use the DNS provided by your ISP), it makes no sense that a `dig` request would return two different values from the *same* DNS server when connected to two different networks.

Comment: @Allan: OP is updated with ping results from  home router's command line.  I agree that the results do not make sense: it's odd that I can view the website from SBUX and not from the home, despite the fact that other PCs in home can access the site.  BTW, the server may be intentionally configured to be non responsive to ping inquiries.

Comment: Yes, `fbo.gov` doesn't respond to pings, but more importantly, it resolved an address:  `35.169.96.154`  What happens on your Mac?  As an aside, when pasting the output from your console, don't use blockquote, use *code formatting* (the *{}* - double braces) for readability.